# Deleting specific class objects stored in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have a problem with my code and I was wondering if someone could have a look, I have a function I have created to delete a specific element from an array. I use a linear search to find the element then I overwrite the element I want to get rid of with the one after as I have not found a way to delete an element specifically. my problem is that the code does not really work as the element does not get overwritten, also is there a way to leave an blank space in the array once the element has been overwritten.

below is my code:

```
void deleteinfo()
{
    string search ;
    int found ;

    cout << "\n Delete A Player's Information \n\n" ;
    cout << "Please Enter The Player's Last Name : " ;
    cin >> search ;

    found=linsearch(search);

    if (found==-1)
    {
        cout << "\n There is no player called " << search ;
    }
    else
    {
        player[found].getFirstName() = player[found + 1].getFirstName() ;
        player[found].getLastName() = player[found + 1].getLastName() ;
        player[found].getAge() == player[found + 1].getAge() ;
        player[found].getCurrentTeam() = player[found + 1].getCurrentTeam() ;
        player[found].getPosition() = player[found + 1].getPosition() ;
        player[found].getStatus() = player[found + 1 ].getStatus() ;

        cout << "\n Player has been deleted." ;
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;
}


int linsearch(string val)
{
    for (int j=0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        if  (player[j].getLastName()==val)
         return j ;         
    }
        return -1 ;
}
```

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code is not productive.  Please use the debugger (or add print statements) to help isolate the problem, and then create a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Almost all containers like `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc. have ways to remove an element from the middle.  C-style arrays are error-prone and tedious.

Comment: i cannot use headers such as vector and list. i am limeited in the way i can code this. thanks

Comment: Like aschepler already said, consider using a standard container. Alternatively, if you HAVE to do it manually, either use a linked list, or (which may be just what you want), set the value of the pointer in the array to NULL. (Assuming you're using an array of pointers instead of 'static' objects)

Comment: Would it also be necessary to move contents of `found + 2` to `found + 1`?

Comment: If deleting from middle is a frequent operation, then consider using a linked-list instead of an array.

Comment: If this code compiles, although you have a lot of warnings, you are overwriting only some temporaries... probably removed by the optimizer :) You should have player[found] = player[found+1] and make sure that Player is copyable...

Comment: *"i cannot use headers such as vector and list."* ... Should we attempt to guess why that is?

Comment: For most classes 'copyable' is a bit difficult though, because you'd essentially have to overload the assignment operator or use a custom constructor. But yeah, there are easier ways than this.

Comment: how would i know if the objects are copyable ?

Answer (score 1):

This is merely an example how you may be able to solve this problem. I'm assuming, that you have a static length array (maximum number of players).

```
Player *Players[MAX_PLAYERS];          //Array with pointers to Player objects.
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYERS; ++i)
    Players[i] = new Players(x, y, z); //Fills the array with some data.
```

Now for your erasing:

```
if(found > 0) {
    delete Players[found];             //Destroys the object in question.
    for(int i = found; i < MAX_PLAYERS - 1; ++i)
        Players[i] = Players[i + 1];   //Moves the entire list up by one.
    Players[MAX_PLAYERS - 1] = NULL;   //Marks the new end of the list.
}
```

This little snippet will not 'copy' the entire object, but rather move them up in the array (without reconstructing any object).

The array is at it's 'end', when you encounter the first NULL pointer (and at MAX_PLAYERS latest), which accounts for your 'blank space'. Alternatively, you can omit the 'moving up' and just destroy the object and set the pointer to NULL. That way, you'll know, that there's no player there.

Comment: how would i know if the objects are copyable ?

Comment: @tarantino The objects themselves don't need to be copied at all. You are moving the entire object, not just the data. Do you know how pointers work? In short, they 'point' to data. So instead of moving the object anywhere, you simply tell the new 'next': Point to that object now. Ah yeah, to access the object from a pointer, you need to use `->` instead of `.`

Comment: thanks i'll have a look at using pointers

Comment: @tarantino Please remember to accept an answer, if it helped you answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is copy all elements that follow the element you want to delete by one position to the left and at end update the new length of the array. For example:

```
for (size_t i = found + 1; i < player_length; ++i) {
    player[i - 1] = player[i];
}
--player_length;
```

The objects in your `player` array must be copyable. I assume you have a variable somewhere that holds the current length of the array ("length" as in how many players it currently has in it, not its total capacity.)

Comment: how would i know if the objects are copyable ?

Comment: @tarantino If the code compiles, they're copyable. Otherwise you'll get errors. An example of non-copyable objects would be if they have a deleted or private assignment operator.

Comment: i have tried your approach but i still do not get the correct output and the code compiles without errors. thanks for yout help

Comment: @tarantino If you think you have a workable approach to this, but can't figure out what's wrong, open a new question.