# Deleting specific class objects stored in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting specific class objects stored in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485780/deleting-specific-class-objects-stored-in-an-array)

I am trying to delete a specific element in an array of class objects. I am overwriting the element I want to delete with the element after it. My algorithm works but the output is not correct, after debugging and going through the code step by step it seems my objects just dont copy, is there a way to copy a class object, I have looked up copy constructors and attempted to write one but it does not seem to have any effect on the output. I would appreciate any help. thanks

below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void storeinfo() ;
void showinfo() ;
void menu() ;
void deleteinfo() ;
void displayallinfo() ;
int linsearch(string val) ;


class user 
{
    string firstname, lastname, currentteam, position, status ;
    int age ;
public:
    user() {};
    user(string fname, string lname, string cteam, string pos, string stat, int age) 
    {
        setFirstName(fname);
        setLastName(lname);
        setCurrentTeam(cteam);
        setPosition(pos);
        setStatus(stat);
        setAge(age);
    } ;
    void setFirstName(string fname)
        {firstname = fname;}
    void setLastName(string lname)
        {lastname = lname;}
    void setCurrentTeam(string cteam)
        {currentteam = cteam;}
    void setPosition(string pos)
        {position = pos;}
    void setStatus(string stat)
        {status = stat;}
    void setAge(int _age)
        {age = _age;}

    string getFirstName()
        {return firstname ;}
    string getLastName()
        {return lastname ;}
    string getCurrentTeam()
        {return currentteam ;}
    string getPosition()
        {return position ;}
    string getStatus()
        {return status ;}
    int getAge()
        {return age ;}
};

user player[20] ;
int arrlength = 3 ;

int main()
{
    menu() ;

    cin.get() ;
    return 0 ;
}

void storeinfo()
{
    string firstname ;
    string lastname ;
    string currentteam ;
    string position;
    string status ;
    int age ;

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n\n Enter First Name : " ; 
        cin >> firstname ;
        player[i].setFirstName(firstname) ;
        cout << "Enter Last Name : " ; 
        cin >> lastname ;
        player[i].setLastName(lastname) ;
        cout << "Enter Player's Age : " ; 
        cin >> age;
        player[i].setAge(age) ;
        cout << "Enter Current Team : " ; 
        cin >> currentteam ;
        player[i].setCurrentTeam(currentteam) ;
        cout << "Enter Position : " ; 
        cin >> position ;
        player[i].setPosition(position) ;
        cout << "Enter Status : " ; 
        cin >> status ;
        player[i].setStatus(status) ;

        cout << "\n\n\n" ;
    }

    /*cout << string(50, '\n');*/

    menu() ;

}

void showinfo()
{
    string search;
    int found ;


    cout << "Please Enter The Player's Last Name : " ;
    cin >> search ;

    found=linsearch(search);

    if (found==-1)
    {
        cout << "\n There is no player called " << search ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n First Name : " << player[found].getFirstName() << "\n" << "Last Name : " << player[found].getLastName() <<
            "\n" << "Age : " << player[found].getAge() << "\n" << "Current Team : " << player[found].getCurrentTeam() << 
            "\n" << "Position : " << player[found].getPosition() << "\n" << "Status :  " << player[found].getStatus()  << "\n\n";
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;

}

void deleteinfo()
{
    int arrlength = 3 ;
    string search ;
    int found ;

    cout << "\n Delete A Player's Information \n\n" ;
    cout << "Please Enter The Player's Last Name : " ;
    cin >> search ;

        found=linsearch(search);

    if (found==-1)
    {
        cout << "\n There is no player called " << search ;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=found + 1; i < arrlength; ++i)
        {
            player[i-1].setFirstName(player[i].getFirstName()) ;
            player[i-1].setLastName(player[i].getLastName()) ;
            player[i-1].setAge(player[i].getAge()) ;
            player[i-1].setCurrentTeam(player[i].getCurrentTeam()) ;
            player[i-1].setPosition(player[i].getPosition()) ;
            player[i-1].setStatus(player[i].getStatus()) ;
        }

        --arrlength ;


        cout << "\n Player has been deleted." ;
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;
}

void displayallinfo()
{
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n First Name : " << player[i].getFirstName() << "\n" << "Last Name : " << player[i].getLastName() <<
            "\n" << "Age : " << player[i].getAge() << "\n" << "Current Team : " << player[i].getCurrentTeam() << 
            "\n" << "Position : " << player[i].getPosition() << "\n" << "Status :  " << player[i].getStatus()  << "\n\n";
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "\n\n MENU" << "\n" ;
    cout << "\n A. Store Player Information" ;
    cout << "\n B. Show Player Informaton" ;
    cout << "\n C. Delete Player Information" ;
    cout << "\n D. Display All Players";
    cout << "\n Z. Exit \n\n" ;

    string x =  "";
    cin >> x ;

    if (x=="a" | x=="A")
    { 
        storeinfo() ;
    }
    else if (x=="b" | x=="B")
    {
        showinfo() ;
    }
    else if (x=="c" | x=="C")
    {
        deleteinfo() ;
    }
    else if (x=="d" | x=="D")
    {
        displayallinfo() ;
    }
    else if (x=="z" | x=="Z")
    {
        exit(0) ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Choice" ;
        menu() ;
    }
}

int linsearch(string val)
{
    for (int j=0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        if  (player[j].getLastName()==val)
         return j ;         
    }
        return -1 ;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you gave us a minimal, complete example (this one is neither).

Comment: @DrewDormann I am asking about copy constructors in this post, it's just the same code

Comment: 1) Holy wall of code, Batman! 2) The copy constructor and assignment operator you wrote are line-for-line identical to those the compiler already provides you for free. 3) Getters are used to get, setters are used to set.

Comment: @ryanbwork that won't work as the variable firstname is private so it would be inaccesible

Comment: @tarantino see my answer, use the setter instead

Comment: I mean an example that we can compile and run to reproduce the error, and is no more complicated than it must be to do so. This code doesn't compile, and it contains a lot of stuff that probably isn't needed.

Comment: @ryanbwork that seems to make sense, i'll try it now

Comment: @beta i have edited the post and added the complete example

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. When I delete the second entry, the third is copied. You don't seem to have tested this.

Comment: Is it your intention to build a continual menu() stackframe, recursing yet-one-more-level with any menu choice given ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`player[i-1].getFirstName()` returns a copy of the instance's firstname member variable. Assigning another value to the output of this function does not change the value stored in the instance itself. Use `player[i-1].setFirstName(player[i].getFirstName())` instead. Also, instead of copying each member in your for loop, you could utilize the assignment operaor via
`player[i-1] = player[i];`

Comment: i just tried your method but there doesnt seem to be any change, the program runs the algorithm succesfully but does not give the correct output. i have included the full code for you to have a look at. Thanks

Comment: Can you give a example test scenario? Are you debugging using the displayallinfo() method or using some print statements? How many players are you inserting, which player are you attempting to delete, etc?

Comment: i am debugging using the displayallinfo() method , inserting 3 players and deleting any of them

Comment: Just copied/pasted your code and compiled it. Deleting players works as expected, so I'm not sure how you're testing to get said results. You just need to delete the last player in the list at the end of your delete method.

Comment: thanks for all your help eventually got it working

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are really not good for this sort of thing.  Consider using std::list.  It also means you can get rid of all the awkward size hardcodings.